# Need help with XMLList in Flex

Tags: xml, apache-flex, actionscript-3, e4x, xmllist

I have XML with the following structure, for example

```
<root>
    <node flag="false"/>
    <node flag="true"/>
    <node flag="false"/>
    <node flag="false"/>
    <node flag="true">
        <node flag="false"/>
        <node flag="true"/>
        <node flag="false"/>
        <node flag="true"/>
    </node>
    <node flag="true"/>
    <node flag="false">
        <node flag="false"/>
        <node flag="true"/>
        <node flag="false"/>
        <node flag="true"/>
    </node>
    <node flag="false"/>
</root>
```

All children have name "node". What I need is to get an XMLList (or XML, no matter), with the same hierarchy, but containing only nodes with the flag "true".

The result I need for my example is:

```
<root>
    <node flag="true"/>
    <node flag="true">
        <node flag="true"/>
        <node flag="true"/>
    </node>
    <node flag="true"/>
</root>
```

Is there any nice way to do this using e4x (without iterating through loop)? I tried to do the following:
xml.node.(@flag=="true"), but the result in this case is:

```
<root>
        <node flag="true"/>
        <node flag="true">
            <node flag="false"/> <!--need to kill this node-->
            <node flag="true"/>
            <node flag="false"/> <!--need to kill this node-->
            <node flag="true"/>
        </node>
        <node flag="true"/>
    </root>
```

Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a one liner in `e4x` as you ask :

```
xml..node.((@flag=="false") && (delete parent().children()[valueOf().childIndex()]))
```

it delete the node to the current `XML` so pay attention to have a copy of your current XML.

By the way you should know that `e4x` just do a loop under the hood, and that one liner will not be faster than a custom loop.

```
var xml:XML=<root>
    <node id="1" flag="false"/>
    <node id="2" flag="true"/>
    <node id="3" flag="false"/>
    <node id="4" flag="false"/>
    <node id="5" flag="true">
        <node id="5.1" flag="false"/>
        <node id="5.2" flag="true"/>
        <node id="5.3" flag="false"/>
        <node id="5.4" flag="true"/>
    </node>
    <node id="6" flag="true"/>
    <node id="7" flag="false">
        <node id="7.1" flag="false"/>
        <node id="7.2" flag="true"/>
        <node id="7.3" flag="false"/>
        <node id="7.4" flag="true"/>
    </node>
    <node id="8" flag="false"/>
</root>

trace("-- before --")
trace(xml.toXMLString())

xml..node.((@flag=="false") && (delete parent().children()[valueOf().childIndex()])) 

trace("\n-- after --")
trace(xml.toXMLString())
```

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you! But I'm a bit confused about the second part of the expression. Could you explain it to me , please? delete parent().children()[valueOf().childIndex()]

Comment: @Timofei Davydik
parent() <- get the parent of the current node
, children() <- get the array of all the children
, valueOf() <- get the current node
, childIndex() <- get the index into the children array.

Comment: @Brian Bishop, that's what i said in my answer, and the question was how to do it with e4x without loop ;)

Comment: Yes, that was exactly what I was looking for! :) Unfortunately there's no another way to point at the current node except parent().children()[valueOf().childIndex()

Comment: @Timofei Davydik If you want to delete the node AFAIK no.

Answer (score 1):

It didn't kill those nodes, cause your condition xml.node.(@flag="true") works only on the direct children of root, you have to make another one for the children of node

Comment: I understand why this happens. And I'm looking for any nice solution. I just don't want to iterate through nodes, getting children, cutting and appending...

Comment: did you try this xml.node.(@flag=="true).node.(@flag=="true")?

Comment: Yes, I tried, it returns one-level XML <node flag="true"/><node flag="true"/>

Comment: what about xml..node.(@flag=="true")?